Using a Private Github Homebrew Tap to distribute a tool in a Private Repository via brew tap
I'm build an internal tool for use at my company. The tool is written in python and uses poetry for dependency management. I'd like to use brew for distributing the tool to anyone at the company, where we use a private github org. I seem to be getting close, but I keep getting stuck on the Github Actions brew test-bot stage in the pipeline, and trying to follow the error messages has me going in a loop. Here is an example of the formula, as well as the github actions workflow.
These files are at github.com/foo/homebrew-tap
/Formula/bar@0.7.0.rb:
class BarAT070 < Formula
  include Language::Python::Virtualenv

  desc "whatever"
  homepage "https://github.com/foo/bar"
  url "git@github.com:foo/bar.git", tag: "v0.7.0", revision: "5bbf5c5c2673d976c8206d5332add7c3xxxxx"
  license ""

  depends_on "python3"

  resource "altgraph" do
    url "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/a8/7145824cf0b9e3c28046520480f207df47e927df83aa9555fb47f8505922/altgraph-0.17.4.tar.gz"
    sha256 "1b5afbb98f6c4dcadb2e2ae6ab9fa994bbb8c1d75f4fa96d340f9437ae454406"
  end

  def install
    virtualenv_create(libexec, "python3")
    virtualenv_install_with_resources
  end

  test do
    system "#{bin}/bar", "--version"
  end
end

/.github/workflows/tests.yml
name: brew test-bot

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    
env:
  HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.HOMEBREW_GITHUB_PAT }}
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.HOMEBREW_GITHUB_PAT }}

jobs:
  test-bot:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-22.04, macos-13]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Set up Homebrew
        id: set-up-homebrew
        uses: Homebrew/actions/setup-homebrew@master
        with:
            token: ${{ github.token }}

      - name: Set Up Git
        run: git config --global credential.helper store && echo "https://$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com" >> ~/.git-credentials

      - name: Cache Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-path }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-hash }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-

      - run: brew test-bot --only-cleanup-before

      - run: brew test-bot --only-setup

      - run: brew test-bot --only-tap-syntax

      - run: brew test-bot --only-formulae
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'

      - name: Upload bottles as artifact
        if: always() && github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: bottles_${{ matrix.os }}
          path: '*.bottle.*'

I keep failing on the brew test-bot --only-formulae stage, any typically with some sort of github.com/foo/bar doesn't exist or 404 on trying to clone the release. as you can see, I have all of the tokens set correctly, as well as a new Personal Access Token with repo scope that I have there as a secret, and still no luck. Has anyone here ever gotten this to work for them? Any examples of working Formulas for private homebrew taps tapping private github repos would be highly appreciated. Thanks!
